# JavaScript autotesting in browsers without webdriver

Tags: javascript, testing, smart-tv

I am developing a js library for smart tv embeded apps, and I would like to make some autotests for my code. The problem is, smarttv's do not provide webdriver interface, so it is impossible to use test runners like karma.

I need a solution that can be embedded to a custom HTML page, run tests by my scenario and log results to a div or console. Which test frameworks are capable of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using https://github.com/substack/tape

Using this lib I bundle tests into a single js via webpack and run them directly inside a specially created smart tv app.

Answer (score 1):

Testcafe is most suitable E2E framework for your needs: http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/

It does not require any additional capabilities from browser, and can be run at least with a stool if it has a browser and connection to the network.

See advanced usage with example and comparation with driver-based E2E tools here: https://60devs.com/functional-testing-of-web-applications-using-testcafe-and-nightwatch.html

Answer (score 0):

Automated tests is not clear question, so if you want unit tests you can use every unit test framework working in browser but it must be setup and this is not easy to be automated you will still need to run it manually.

But now is great solution called [Suitest](http://www.suite.st/) which is handling mainly TV platforms and write tests is easy even non-programmer guys, there is lot of ways and also CI integration option.

So it is easy to be configured to run automatically with each commit by some CI or whatever you want.